Using multiple application.yml with spring project running in docker container
Im facing an issue where im trying to load application.yml depending on what profile is active. I have the standard application.yml, and another application-docker.yml . They are both under resources where they should be stored. There are some properties in the application-docker.yml which are not in application.yml
I tried to set docker as an active profile when i run the project locally with intelliJ, and it works as it should. It gets all the properties from both yml files, and overrides the ones in the normal application.yml with the ones in application-docker.yml.
The problem is that when i build the docker image and try to run it in a container, it doesnt seem to pick up the application-docker.yml file, only application.yml.
Ive checked and made sure that docker is the active profile by reading the logs, and ive also run the command jar tf /app/dev-epj-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar | grep application-docker.yml inside the docker container to make sure that application-docker.yml is included in the jar.
An example of a key that is only in the docker yml and not the standard one is server.ssl.key-store. This works fine locally, but with docker only i get this error message:
Required key 'server.ssl.key-store' not found
I cant find out why it wont read the application-docker.yml when i run it with docker. It works fine when i run it with docker through IntelliJ, but not without IntelliJ.
The code is written in kotlin. Im using Spring boot 3.2.2
Please let me know if any additional info is needed.
My dockerfile is as following:
FROM maven:3.8.5-openjdk-17 AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY pom.xml .
RUN mvn dependency:go-offline -B
COPY src ./src

RUN mvn clean package -DskipTests

FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/target/*.jar dev-epj-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
COPY src/main/resources/keystore/localhost.p12 /app/keystore/localhost.p12


ENV SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=DOCKER

EXPOSE 7073

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "dev-epj-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]

Update: Seemed to be an issue with docker after all... Spent almost 2 hours debugging it, but the solution was just to restart docker (restarted the mac just to be safe). You live and learn i guess.

#1 Somehow the "keystore" error complicates the understanding of your question. #2 Use a minimalist project like this to reproduce your error (build is not taking the expected properties) locally and with docker. Share the results. #3 Also you can share the code to help you directly #4 Docker is not the problem #5 To have a pre-existent file (yaml) in the server or in the resources folder are not devops compatible. Can you hear another strategy?

@JRichardsz The error was just an example of a property inside application-docker.yml that my configuration class cant read. There are others aswell.
I will try to recreate the problem in the link you sent.
Its hard to share the code i work on sadly because it is related to work, and i would have to do alot of manual change to filter out sensitive information

Share the replication, not your real code. Your error is related to properties, not the controllers, repositories, etc

If the alternate property file is application-docker.yml (all lowercase), do you also need to set SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker (lowercase)?  Also remember that you can set individual Spring properties directly via environment variables and that you can inject a YAML or properties file at deploy time, which may be more maintainable than trying to "bake in" environment-specific properties to your jar file.

@DavidMaze It doesnt have to be all lowercase, but i could have it lowercase aswell. I answered my to the thread, but it was a docker issue it seems... Worked fine after rebooting.

Thanks @JRichardsz . I used your project to test having multiple application.yml files depending on environment, and it worked fine with yours. Figured something was wrong with docker after that, so i rebooted and it fixed.

#1 Reproduce or isolate the issue in a clean template helped me a lot #2 To have a pre-existent file (yaml) in the server or in the resources folder are not devops compatible. I advice you to use env variables in the future  #3 Delete the part of key-store. It confuses us

Seemed to be an issue with docker after all... Spent almost 2 hours debugging it, but the solution was just to restart docker (restarted the mac just to be safe). You live and learn i guess

To improve your answer, when you can, add more details. Did you restart the docker daemon or just the container?
